# How do I overwrite a file using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

```
New-Item -Path "C:\aws" -Name "script.ps1" -ItemType "file" -Value "text in file"
```

I am trying to create a file using the above command, if the file already exists I have to replace it with new file, it will have same file name. Please help

Comment: When asking a question about a specific command you should be sure to include the result — especially any error messages — of running that command.  However, I can already see you're missing the `-Force` parameter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the force — specifically, the `-Force` parameter...

```
New-Item -Path "C:\aws" -Name "script.ps1" -ItemType "file" -Value "text in file" -Force
```

Whether `script.ps1` already exists or not, upon success it will contain the exact content `text in file`.

Its use is also demonstrated in [example #9](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item#example-9-use-the-force-parameter-to-overwrite-existing-files) of the [`New-Item` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item)...

> ## Example 9: Use the -Force parameter to overwrite existing files
>
> This example creates a file with a value and then recreates the file using `-Force`. This overwrites The existing file and it will lose it's content as you can see by the length property
>
> ```
> PS> New-Item ./TestFile.txt -ItemType File -Value 'This is just a test file'
>
>     Directory: C:\Source\Test
> Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
> ----                -------------         ------ ----
> -a----         5/1/2020   8:32 AM             24 TestFile.txt
>
> New-Item ./TestFile.txt -ItemType File -Force
>
>     Directory: C:\Source\Test
> Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
> ----                -------------         ------ ----
> -a----         5/1/2020   8:32 AM              0 TestFile.txt
> ```

Omitting `-Force` from the second invocation of `New-Item` produces the error `New-Item : The file '...\TestFile.txt' already exists.`.

Comment: I asked on Meta about the Markdown rendering of this answer: [Why does this header-within-a-blockquote render as expected in the preview but not the final post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399921/150605)

Comment: I get the error eventho I have `-Force`